# Webdev, frontend and backend: how know if entity belongs to user?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, rest

I have users and projects in a web application. Each user can have n projects. Each project can have m users. From a DB point of view, there are three tables: user, project, and user2project (to map the user and project n:m relation).

The backend is a simple crud-rest api (relational). Furthermore I'm using a JWT-token based authentication.

My frontend would show a project via projectId:

localhost:4300/projects/941343/

If the shown project belongs to the currently logged in user, my frontend should show additional buttons, such as "edit project".

But how can I know, that this project belongs to the currently logged in user?

**Idea 1:**

Have my backend always return the userids when the project is returned.

Sample response:

```
{
    projectid: "941343",
    title: "Some Project-Title",
    description "Some Project-Description",
    user2project: [
        { userid: "902319" },
        { userid: "299322" },
        { userid: "920392" }
    ]
}
```

With this approach I would just check if the project-object holds a user2project-object with the same userid as the currently logged in user.

Disadvantage: additional join in backend and bigger payload

**Idea 2:**

Once a user is logged in, I would persist not only the UserId, but also all ProjectIds of that user.

As such, I could then simply check the ID of the url with the persisted data.

Disadvantage: whenever someone else adds my user to a project, that change is not registered until I log in again.

Question: are these ideas viable for this purpose? Is there a better approach even?

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with your first approach. If you wanted to... you could also have the check of the user at the database level (providing the userId and then joining with that), without the need to send all the userid records of a project to the backend (so no additional payload). At the end you will only have a boolean... projectOwner: true

Comment: Can you update your answer with the type of authentication you use? This could become part of an authorisation approach and require no app code logic at all. I.E using RBAC or similar. However, without the type of authentication I can't provide a complete answer.

Comment: @Isolated: Sure thing! My authentication is token based (JWT)

Comment: @d3bgger: actually that's a good idea, so the backend would just do the evaluation and return the result as part of the project-payload

Answer (score 1):

If you know both the user id and the project id, the you could see whether or not this SQL query returns any result:

```
SELECT * WHERE user_id=X AND project_id=Y
```

You do the check on the server side. To check the same from the client side, you create an API call for it.

Answer (score 0):

> If the shown project belongs to the currently logged in user, my frontend should show additional buttons, such as "edit project".

I originally misread your question, I feel others may have also.

Using the authenticated user, check if the authenticated user === project owner inside your component, this could be as simple as:

```html
<div *ngIf="authenticatedUser.id === project.ownerId">
<!-- SHOW BUTTONS -->
</div>
```

You would do this inside your ProjectSingleComponent, or whatever it's named inside your app.

If you support multiple users with the option to make changes, then use an .includes instead, checking if the array includes the authenticated user.

This is something RBAC would help with (not the buttons, practice in general). I'd encourage taking a look at what that would entail for future reference (although this is now off-topic to your original question).

EDIT: If you are looking to securely manage who has access to what, then this is the role of authorization and should be implemented using permissions, plus an additonal layer of database isolation (either physically or logically), to truly prevent access. If it's only the buttons you're interested in, the above approach may work.

An example to reflect my comment:

```html
<div *ngIf="project.owners.includes(authenticatedUser.id)">
  <!-- SHOW BUTTONS -->
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry perhaps my original post was not fully clear. Yep, that's variant 1, to add the userId (=ownerId) to the project's payload:) I was not aware of RBAC, and will look into that right away, thanks for now!

Comment: What database system are you using? RBAC won't help with adding those buttons (but it will help with preventing unauthorized access against resources), would it be possible to have an ownerId on the project? Or even just an array of IDs? That reduces the amount of data returned per payload. I.E: `owners`, if your DB doesn't support arrays, then you could use a string with a delimiter. Then in your Angular, check if the authenticated user is in that array (use `.split('|')` or whatever the delimiter in the case of strings).